# Unity C# Cannot update a Ui text label CYOA: Text based. Trying to understand references, initialization, and the update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

UPDATE: 5/27/16

https://github.com/Linkman214/DawnLake/blob/master/Text101/Assets/TextController.cs

Renaldo, you've been a tremendous help. I have one issue, and that is with a method that is suppose to deduct money -2, and then update the label.  However, my code seems to pull both health and orens(money) into the negatives, my guess would be because of the current state constantly being updated in the update() method. Here are all the instances where they are called.

```
public class TextController : MonoBehaviour {
public Text text;
public Text Healthlabel;
public Text OrensLabel;

private enum States {Start,Gossip,Survey_0,Drink_0,Witcher,Drink_1,TakeJob,Sleep};
private States myState;
int money= 2;
int health=100;
// Use this for initialization


void Start () {
 myState=States.Start;
 update_health();
 update_money();
}

public void update_health(){ Healthlabel.text=health.ToString(); Healthlabel=gameObject.GetComponent<Text>(); } 



public void update_money(){ OrensLabel.text=money.ToString(); OrensLabel=gameObject.GetComponent<Text>(); }

void state_TakeJob(){
text.text= "The Alderman has collected a pool among the fisherman. Come dawn, they'll be out by the dock," +
" hollering for brave souls to join another hunting party." +  
" If you're interested, we have vacant rooms upstairs for 2 orens a night\n\n" +
" Times are tough indeed, press S to rent a room and sleep for the night";
money= money-2;
update_money();


if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))  {myState=States.Sleep;}



and this is what the update method looks like



void Update () {

print(myState);
if (myState==States.Start) {state_Start();}
else if (myState==States.Drink_0)    {state_Drink_0();}
else if (myState==States.Survey_0)   {state_Survey_0();}
else if (myState==States.Gossip)     {state_Gossip();}
else if (myState==States.Witcher)    {state_Witcher();}
else if (myState==States.Sleep)      {state_Sleep();}
else if (myState==States.TakeJob)    {state_TakeJob();}
```

Comment: You need to reference each Text component (in your case this means every text ui element) individually. So if you have three different text elements in your scene, you need e.g. `Text health` + `Text money` + `Text dialogue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this.

For your case I suggest you to create 2 extras texts, so you will be able to reposition your UI in the scene.

Another way is to create a funcion like this:

```
private void UpdateOutputText(string output){
    this.text.text = "money: " + money + " health: " + health + "\n" +
                     output;
}
```

Comment: I've added the following                                                  <public Text text;
public Text Healthlabel;
 public Text OrensLabel;                                                                            void Start () {
  myState=States.Start;
   update_health();                                                                                                                private void update_health(){
 Healthlabel.text=health.ToString();
 OrensLabel.text=money.ToString();}                  However I am getting a null reference exception in update_health()>

Comment: Have you drag in your script variable through the inspector?

Comment: Yes, I made sure all scripts were aligned with the proper text variables. I think it may have something to do with my update_health() method not returning anything in the parameter?

Comment: I saw your code on your git. I have 2 things to say: indentation matter a lot and the another is make sure your Text UI are attached on your script. You configure it on the scene.

Comment: I just downloaded your entire project and the problem is that your have 3 objects of your class attached to three different objects. I recommend you to attach your component only to your 'Text'(it is its name on your project) GameObject and link all three on it just for testing. As a good practice you should have some sort of GameManager object.